# How to bind SQL CE Database to DataGrid control?

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server-ce

I have a SQL CE Database that I want to display its data on a **DataGrid**. 
I could do a SQL query then do a loop of **Items.Add** to the **DataGrid**. But I wonder is it possible to bind the SQL CE database to **DataGrid** directly without refreshing through a loop or using DataReader.

For instance, if there are new rows added to the Database, the DataGrid will display it automatically without me manually refreshing it (eg. a Button with SQL query).

I tried along the below approach but it didn't work out:

```
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = connString.Database;
```

Any suggestion? (BTW, I am creating all my Controls in run-time, so no XAML solution)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rows are not in a database but in a table. A database can have more then one table. So binding the database will not work. I also think you have to get the data out of the table before you can bind them. I am no database expert but I never saw direct binding with a database table.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind a grid to a specific table.

What you do is fill a data set thru a data adapter and then bind the grid.

```
cmd = New SqlCeCommand("select * from testtable", conn)

If conn.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then conn.Open()

datAdapter = New SqlCeDataAdapter(cmd)
datSet = New DataSet

datAdapter.Fill(datSet, "myTable")

myBind = New BindingSource(datSet, "myTable")

Me.grid.DataSource = myBind
```